# sql query not working in php, displaying relevant results based on ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an original query in which the user selects a genre, (and then this genres id and name is displayed on the following page), however along with this I want the games associated with that ID to also be displayed.

So when a user clicks game genre - action, games 1/2/3 etc to be displayed and if that user then clicks multiplayer, games 4/5/6 to be displayed.

I'm not sure how to echo these statements either, but here's what I have tried.

```
ggID = gameGenre
gaID = gameID
geID = genreID


<?php

$ggID= $_POST['ggID'];

$sql = "SELECT * from Game WHERE gaID = '$ggID' AND geID = '$ggID'";
$result = mysql_query ($sql);

while ($result_detail = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
    {
      echo $result;
    }
?>
```

EDIT: Also I get the error, undefined index ggID

Comment: Your code is widely susceptible to SQL injection. Immediately stop using it.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you need to remove "gaID = '$ggID' AND " from the WHERE clause, unless the Game ID and Genre ID are identical.

Comment: tried this but not displaying anything, how should I echo the resulting games from selecting the genre?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ggID= $_POST['ggID'];
$sql = "SELECT * from Game WHERE geID = '$ggID'";// IF geId is an int field you will have to remove the singe quotes.
$result = mysql_query ($sql);

while ($result_detail = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
{
echo $result_detail["gaId"]; // Or whatever field names you want. gaId should be a mySql field
}
```

Comment: PHP is telling you exactly what the problem is:  ggID is not being sent with the $_POST data.  if $ggID doesn't exist, then obviously the query isn't going to work.  You should check if it is set - if ( isset($_POST['ggID']) ) { do something } else { stop }

Comment: It possibly means that $_POST doesn't has that value. Check the HTML form and see if name field has been set. Something like name="ggId"